# No node error when executing Hadoop command

Tags: sqoop

Getting error when executing a 'cat' command in Hadoop. Tried increasing space to the node still getting the error:

> INFO hdfs.DFSClient: No node available for BP-333635372-127.0.0.1-1508779710286:blk_1073743948_3135 file=/user/cloudera/sqoop_import/departments/part-m-00000
>
> INFO hdfs.DFSClient: Could not obtain BP-333635372-127.0.0.1-1508779710286:blk_1073743948_3135 from any node:  No live nodes contain current block Block locations: Dead nodes: . Will get new block locations from namenode and retry...